# yum fails to update

Tags: centos, yum

yum fails to update CentOs 7.6.

it says `Requires: qt5-qtbase(x86-64) = 5.9.2` but on the other side it says `Removing: qt5-qtbase-5.9.2-3.el7.x86_64` !!

How can I fix this?

thank you

```
--> Processing Dependency: qt5-qtbase(x86-64) = 5.9.2 for package: qt5-qtstyleplugins-5.0.0-26.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: qt5-qtbase(x86-64) = 5.9.2 for package: qt5-qtquick1-5.7.1-1.2bc722agit.el7.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: qt5-qtstyleplugins-5.0.0-26.el7.x86_64 (@epel)
           Requires: qt5-qtbase(x86-64) = 5.9.2
           Removing: qt5-qtbase-5.9.2-3.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
               qt5-qtbase(x86-64) = 5.9.2-3.el7
           Updated By: qt5-qtbase-5.9.7-2.el7.x86_64 (base)
               qt5-qtbase(x86-64) = 5.9.7-2.el7
Error: Package: qt5-qtquick1-5.7.1-1.2bc722agit.el7.x86_64 (@epel)
           Requires: qt5-qtbase(x86-64) = 5.9.2
           Removing: qt5-qtbase-5.9.2-3.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
               qt5-qtbase(x86-64) = 5.9.2-3.el7
           Updated By: qt5-qtbase-5.9.7-2.el7.x86_64 (base)
               qt5-qtbase(x86-64) = 5.9.7-2.el7
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

**update :**

enabled repos:

```
[mehrdad@MHRS ~]$ yum repolist enabled
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.alpix.eu
 * centos-sclo-rh: ftp.uni-bayreuth.de
 * centos-sclo-sclo: ftp.uni-bayreuth.de
 * epel: mirror.redium.net
 * extras: centos.mirror.iphh.net
 * nux-dextop: mirror.li.nux.ro
 * rpmfusion-free-updates: mirror.ehv.weppel.nl
 * rpmfusion-nonfree-updates: mirror.ehv.weppel.nl
 * updates: ftp.agdsn.de
repo id                           repo name                               status
!base/7/x86_64                    CentOS-7 - Base                         10,097
!centos-sclo-rh/x86_64            CentOS-7 - SCLo rh                       8,548
!centos-sclo-sclo/x86_64          CentOS-7 - SCLo sclo                       804
!epel/x86_64                      Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - 13,413
!extras/7/x86_64                  CentOS-7 - Extras                          304
!google-chrome                    google-chrome                                3
!nodesource/x86_64                Node.js Packages for Enterprise Linux 7     43
!nux-dextop/x86_64                Nux.Ro RPMs for general desktop use      2,718
!rpmfusion-free-updates/x86_64    RPM Fusion for EL 7 - Free - Updates       248
!rpmfusion-nonfree-updates/x86_64 RPM Fusion for EL 7 - Nonfree - Updates     77
!sublime-text                     Sublime Text - x86_64 - Stable               2
!updates/7/x86_64                 CentOS-7 - Updates                         319
repolist: 36,576
```

Comment: The question is: what are you installing? What make `yum` remove qt5-qtbase ? Maybe some other package is being installed that `obsoletes` qt5-base ?

Comment: I just did 'sudo yum update'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There does not seem to be a real solution for this. `qt5-qtstyleplugins` from the `epel` repository requires `qt5-qtbase` with the exact version `5.9.2`, however this version is not available anymore in the `base` repository.

If you want your `yum update` to succeed, you can exclude these packages from updates:

```
yum update --exclude=qt5-qt*
```

see [here](https://tecadmin.net/exclude-packages-from-yum-update/) for more information on excluding packages from yum updates.